# Disambiguating the word "command" in Linux

Tags: terminology

The word *command* refers to two different concepts in Linux:

1. An executable program, such as *grep* (or a shell built-in, such as *cd*). Example usage: "Here are the top 10 Linux commands you should learn."
2. A full text string sent to the shell for execution, such as *grep com /etc/hosts*. Example usage: "Type a Linux command and press Enter."

Does anyone have any best practices for avoiding this ambiguity when writing prose about Linux commands? Here are some attempts I've rejected already:

- Using the word *program* or *executable* for meaning #1. It's inaccurate for shell built-ins.
- Using the phrase *command line* for meaning #2. That's confusing because "command line" is also a synonym for "shell."
- Using the phrase *command string* for meaning #2. It's imprecise because both #1 and #2 are strings.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: In my experience, the ambiguity is not avoided; it is generally clear from context which meaning is intended. (I have over 30 years experience in IT.)

Comment: Aren't grep, awk, bc, cut, etc, _utilities_?

Comment: In which situation would you expect the difference to cause harm? Examples please.

Comment: I don't even see the ambiguity. You need to *command* `grep` from a shell (yes, you could `exec()` it too). For Linux prose ... all of them are "full text strings".

Comment: External commands with their own binaries (such as `grep`) are indeed commands, but so too are builtin commands (such as `if`), which is why the descriptive adjective 'builtin' exists.

I would argue that if you want precise terminology you can distinguish between a command (e. g. `cp`), and a command line (e. g. `cp source destination`) and a command line _interface_ (e. g. a virtual terminal).

Comment: This seems like an imagined ambiguity: I thought grep was a "command" or "utility" and the rest of the line was/were "options" and "arguments" (sometimes "parameters")

Comment: your second point contains incorrect info ... `command line interface` is also synonym for shell ... also refered as CLI ... `command line` would be what is typed into the CLI

Comment: @jsotola Surely a command line is also the string passed to [the libc *system* function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), isn’t it? If the command interpreter can parse that string syntactically without error, it can then do whatever all it has specified should be done. But I do take your point that this fuzzy idea of a "command line" in interactive use is probably worth separating from a complete syntactic statement grammatically. That’s why `foo && bar; zap` is syntactically two statements but one command line. You could pass that to `system`, or type it plus CR to `sh`.

Comment: For those claiming there's no ambiguity, or that it's generally clear from context: I just [wrote an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68014495/zsh-permission-denied-users-myname) where I had to try to explain that the first word of a command is the... um... command. I settled on "program" for the utility/commandname/whatever; hopefully that's clear enough to the asker. (And yes, I know the "program" isn't always the first word, or an actual program, or...)

Comment: FWIW, `sed`, `ex`, `vi` have `i`, `c`, `s`... *commands* as well. `gdb` has `break`, `print`, `bt` *commands*, etc.

Comment: @jsotola: That is true, but note that it is common to abbreviate `command line interface` to `command line` (eg "Next you'll need to enter the following at the command line")

Comment: It is somewhat ironic that a question about imprecise terminology consistently mis-uses the term "Linux".

Comment: Do you need a term that includes shell builtins and aliases as well as program names?

Comment: @DopeGhoti, you picked a bad example - `if` is a syntactic _keyword_ rather than a built-in command.  Examples of the latter are `read`, `set` and `exec`.

Answer (score 18):

POSIX **refers to the things that are like `grep` and `cd` as "[utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_439)"**, and **reserves "[command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_104)" for the instructions**. Used consistently, these terms are unambiguous.

---

To address your cases in turn

1. "An executable program, such as grep (or a shell built-in, such as cd)" [is a *utility*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_439):

   > **Utility** A program, excluding [special built-in utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) provided as part of the Shell Command Language, that can be called by name from a shell to perform a specific task, or related set of tasks.

   Which is [further clarified with](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_22):

   > The system may implement certain utilities as shell functions or built-in utilities

   to be explicit that this incorporates ordinary utilities like `true` that are commonly found as shell builtins.

   Formally, "[special built-in utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14)" are separated from utilities not further specified; these are things like `break`, `.`, `eval`, `set`, and `trap`, which affect the shell's internal state, but they *do not* include `cd`, which is a regular built-in. Outside of the nuanced needs of the specification (certain variable assignment behaviour differs and they are not available with `execvp`), "utility" suffices to cover both categories at the user level. Articles of shell syntax such as `if` and `while` are not utilities at all.
2. "A full text string sent to the shell for execution, such as `grep com /etc/hosts`" [is a *command*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_104):

   > **Command** A directive to the shell to perform a particular task.

   Commands do include simple commands like `grep com /etc/hosts`, pipelines, and compound commands like `if` constructs and grouping commands with `( ... )`, but the word "command" never refers to a utility itself. Within a command, a *[command name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01)* may appear that identifies a utility or a function: the command name in `grep com /etc/hosts` is `grep`, referring to [the grep utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).

---

Vernacular uses of "command" to mean a utility or function may be disambiguated by context, but the formal meaning is only of an instruction. If total avoidance of ambiguity is required, **you can consistently use "utility" and "command"** for those two roles.

You probably can't expect users to make that distinction themselves, though, so search-engine-optimised "top 10 Linux commands" articles are probably making the right choice for their incentives.

Comment: This is mostly correct. The loose language the asker mentions happens only when speaking of input to the shell, not when calling library functions (like from libc) or syscalls (kernel traps). And yet this too is one single solitary shell command, despite not being a particular single program: `status=ˋ((dd if=$device ibs=64k 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- 4>&-; echo $? >&4) | egrep -v "$dd_noise" 1>&2 3>&- 4>&-) 4>&1ˋ`. Good luck counting [how many separate new program images](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655735/2649) the kernel execs for that one. :)

Comment: `ls` is an example of a string that is a commonly-used command, and *also* the name of the utility the command invokes.  (Like other utilities often used with no args, like `date` or `cal`.)  On most systems, `/bin/ls` is the executable that implements that utility.

Comment: some FTP or SFTP or WebDAV... clients also have a `ls` *command* which doesn't invoke an `ls` executable file (though sometimes causes a `ls` command to be executed on the remote server). Note that in shells where `ls` is or can be builtin, that builtin `ls` is still referred to as an utility.

Comment: `google-chrome` is DEFINITELY a command but I would not call it a utility

Answer (score 6):

## <sup><sub>SUMMARY</sub></sup>

The type of ambiguity you reference perceiving here is best remedied by using such terms as a *program*,
an *executable file*, or simply an *executable* for the one that has/is a path,
versus *shell command* or even [*command
line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Beginning..._Was_the_Command_Line)
when you want to reference everything you type into your **command
interpreter**.

---

## Historical Context

The index to early printings of *The C Programming Language* ("K&R",
Prentice-Hall) contained only a single mention of the word *command*, and
not for that word specifically but for ***command-line arguments***.  This
small kernel of meaning provides the critical seed that germinated and
ramified into all later uses. From page 111 of one 1978 printing:

> ## 5.11 Command-line arguments
>
> In environments that support C, there is a way to pass command-line
> arguments or parameters to a program when it begins executing.

That is, the word *command* is used uniquely in a shell context (because a shell by definition is a *command
interpreter*), be that in interactive use or in scripted programming. The authors continue with this example:

> The simplest illustration of the necessary declarations and use is the program `echo`, which simply echoes its command-line arguments on a single line, separated by blanks. That is, if the command
>
> ```
> echo hello, world
> ```
>
> is given, the output is
>
> ```
>  hello, world
> ```

Notice how K&R talk about programs and command lines there. In other words, it’s what IEEE’s [POSIX 1003.2](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/appa_02.htm#:%7E:text=POSIX%201003.2%20itself%20consists%20of,utilities%20like%20the%20vi%20editor.) is all about, ***not*** what [POSIX 1003.1](https://standards.ieee.org/project/1003_1.html) is. In general terms, Dot-1 covers C programming, while Dot-2 covers shell programming.

And shell programming not C programming is what you’re really talking about here. That’s why the intro to [Section 1 of the
Unix Programmer’s Manual](http://man.openbsd.org/intro) mentions commands not function calls:

> ### NAME
>
> intro — introduction to general commands (tools and utilities)
>
> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> The manual pages in section 1 contain most of the commands which comprise
> the BSD user environment. Some of the commands included in section 1 are
> text editors, command shell interpreters, searching and sorting tools, file
> manipulation commands, system status commands, remote file copy commands,
> mail commands, compilers and compiler tools, formatted output tools, and
> line printer commands.
>
> All commands set a status value upon exit which may be tested to see if the
> command completed normally. The exit values and their meanings are
> explained in the individual manuals. Traditionally, the value 0 signifies
> successful completion of the command.

If you were speaking in 1003.1 lingo, you might call it the string argument
to [the *system* function in the C
library](http://man.openbsd.org/system.3).  That's because it is not a
syscall itself but a library function that employs various syscalls
under the hood, one of which is
[`execve`](http://man.openbsd.org/execve.2). That syscall takes a constant
`char *` argument as its first argument, which is the path to the
executable file in the file system.

## Published Solutions

One published solution consistently uses the following definitions:

> ### executable file
>
> A *file* that is specially marked to tell the *operating system* that it’s okay
> to run this file as a program. Usually shortened to “executable”.

> ### command
>
> In *shell* programming, the syntactic combination of a program name
> and its arguments. More loosely, anything you type to a shell (a
> command interpreter) that starts it doing something. [...]

> ### command-line arguments
>
> The values you supply along with a program name when you tell a
> *shell* to execute a *command*. [...]

> ### command name
>
> The name of the *program* currently executing, as typed on the *command
> line*. [...]

<sup>Taken from the fourth edition of *Programming Perl* (O’Reilly), and here used
by kind permission of that book’s authors. :)</sup>.

If you’re lucky, you can find all those yourself, and more, merely by
typing this simple command line into your shell so that it runs the *man* executable/program for you:

```
man perlglossary
```

But if you aren't that lucky, [you can also find them here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary).

## Shell Commands

This could be a shell command:

```
exec 2>errs.out
```

Notice that nothing was `exec`’d there; we’ve just rearranged a file descriptor.

Ditto here:

```
exec 5<&0   # save old stdin
exec 0<&3   # read some_var
exec 0<&4   # read another_var
exec 0<&5   # restore it
```

So each line in a script is a “command”, even here (where I leave as an exercise to the reader how many actual `execve` syscalls it begets when run in full):

```
#!/bin/sh
device=/dev/rmt8
dd_noise='^[0-9]+\+[0-9]+ records (in|out)$'
exec 3>&1
status=`((dd if=$device ibs=64k 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- 4>&-; echo $? >&4) | egrep -v "$dd_noise" 1>&2 3>&- 4>&-) 4>&1`
exit $status
```

<sub>Taken from the venerable jeremiad [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html),
again used here by kind permission blah blah blah. :)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

A rather simple solution ([and the standard philosophic and linguistic dodge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction)) is to distinguish between **Using** the word *command*, and **Mentioning** the word *command*. For instance, certain words perform actions, even in ordinary English, and their Use is how they do it. If you say "I do" under the proper circumstances, you might get married, for instance. But not if you're quoting what somebody else might say. Anything quoted is a Mention, not a Use.

So the first list of commands are not uses of commands; they're mentions of commands.

The second examples, like my fav

- `$ rev wordlist | sort | rev > speculum`
  (which produces a reverse-alphabetized copy of `wordlist`)

will actually do something, so they're definitely Uses.

Comment: Use and abuse of (natural language) grammar is off-topic.

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t see what this has to do with the question. Consider this: *What’s the longest day in the year?* There are two answers: (1) the summer solstice, because it’s ~15 hours long, and (2) the day we go off daylight saving time, because it’s 25 hours long (exactly, possibly ±1 or 2 seconds) — depending on two different interpretations of the word ***day***. “command” is analogous to “day” here.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider **there's no need to** as an answer, as the ambiguity described causes no harm anyway.

In all contexts I've seen, when the word "command" refers to an executable program, it's always something an end user would type into a shell to get it running. I've never seen expressions like "*the `init` command*" or "*the `ld-linux.so` command*".

When "command" refers to a command-line program, it always actually refers to "the family of commands that begins with the said program". For example, when you say "*the `grep` command*", you're talking about all the things you can do with the `grep` program, which forms "a family of commands". This holds for partial commands as well, like the saying "*the `apt install` command is for installing packages*" when the full command `apt install` does nothing useful usually.